# Android with SDL2 not receiving keyboard events for numbers/letters

Tags: android, sdl, keyboard-events

I have ported an application to **Android** using the **SDL Android template project** that comes with the source code.

Unfortunately after building and running the application, I found out that it doesn't receive **Keyboard Events** for **numbers/letters**. Although it does reiceve **Keyboard Events** for <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>, <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and etc.

Although I cannot debug my C++ code, I backtracked the incoming keyboard events back to the function :

```
    public boolean sendKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
```

In the class **SDLInputConnection** that extends **BaseInputConnection**.

Am I missing something? Where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, input from software-keyboard on SDL-Android template project is interpreted as **TextInput**. So to catch the poll event you have to include an **SDL_TEXTINPUT** case.